# Sort Posts showing first the posts with a selected category

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have a Wordpress page with a portfolio and I need to sort this showing first the posts with "featured" category selected.

All the items have a category like "table", "chair"... and I can filter by that, but I need that if I mark an item with "featured" category, this appears in the top of the list whe I show all products or the products in a category (ej: table).

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: paste the code you use to sort categories other than featured

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved the issue with this approach:

```
<?php 
   //Get posts with "Featured" category
   $featured= query_posts('post_type=portfolio&projecttype=featured&posts_per_page=-1'); 
   //Get all posts
   $posts=query_posts('post_type=portfolio&project-type='. query_categories() .'&posts_per_page=-1');

   //I merge removing duplicated posts with array_unique
   $final_posts = array_unique(array_merge( $destacados, $posts ), SORT_REGULAR);

   foreach ( $final_posts as $key => $post ) {
      setup_postdata( $post );

      //Use wp methods to show info (ej:the_title();)
   }
?>
```